Covering space of a path connected, locally path connected space
I am learning covering spaces, lifting criterion, etc. In the lifting criterion (Hatcher, p. 61 Proposition 1.33):


Suppose given a covering space $p \colon (\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0) \to (X,x_0)$ and a map $f\colon (Y, y_0)\to (X,x_0)$ with $Y$ path-connected and locally path-connected. Then, a lift $\tilde{f}\colon (Y,y_0)\to (\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0)$ of $f$ exists if and only if $f_{\ast}(\pi_1(Y,y_{0})) \subset p_{\ast}(\pi_{1}(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0))$.


In the proof, it seems the assumption of $Y$ being path-connected and locally path-connected seems important and cannot be dropped. However, what I am confused is that sometimes they are dropped (in Hatcher's book) but proofs still use the lifting criterion. For example, on p.67 Proposition 1.37:


If $X$ is path-connected locally path-connected, then two path-connected covering spaces $p_1 \colon \tilde{X}_1 \to X$ and $p_2: \tilde{X}_2 \to X$ are isomorphic via an isomorphism $f \colon \tilde{X}_1\to \tilde{X}_2$ taking a basepoint $\tilde{x}_1\in p_1^{-1}(x_0)$ to a basepoint $\tilde{x}_{2}\in p_{2}^{-1}(x_0)$ iff $p_{1\ast}(\pi_{1}(\tilde{X}_1,\tilde{x}_1)) = p_{2\ast}(\pi_{1}(\tilde{X}_2,\tilde{x}_2))$.


Here, there is no assumption about $\tilde{X}_1$ being locally path connected but the proof uses the lifting criterion.
Moreover, Proposition 1.39 of Hatcher:


Let $p: (\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0)\to (X, x_0)$ be a path-connected covering space of the path-connected, locally path-connected space $X$, and let $H$ be the subgroup $p_{\ast}(\pi_1(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0)) \subset \pi_1(X,x_0)$. Then, ...


I didn't write the whole statement here, but the proof also uses the lifting criterion.
So, the assumption of the domain space being locally path-connected seemed to be dropped in some places (when the map is a covering map). Is it always okay to drop locally path-connected when the corresponding map is a covering map? If so, why?
Also, is it possible to drop locally path-connected when the corresponding map is not a covering map? Finally, if we drop the assumption that a covering space is path-connected, will this be a problem, i.e. can we not use the lifting criterion anymore?
Thank you for reading this all the way here!

You should have no trouble proving that if $X$ is locally path-connected, then any covering $\tilde{X}$ of $X$ is also locally path-connected (Hint: a covering map is a local homeomorphism).

A covering map $p : \tilde X \to X$ is a local homeomorphism which means that each $\tilde x \in \tilde X$ has an open neighborhood $V$ such that $ p(V)$ is open in $X$ and $p_V :  V \xrightarrow{p} p(V)$ is a homeomorphism.
We shall prove

Let $p : \tilde X \to X$ be a local homeomorphism. If $X$ is locally path connected, then also $\tilde X$ is locally path connected. The converse is true provided $p$ is surjective.


Let $X$ be locally path connected.

Let $\tilde x \in \tilde X$ and $W$ be an open neigborhood an open neighborhood of $\tilde x$. There exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $\tilde x$ such that $ p(V)$ is open in $X$ and $p_V :  V \xrightarrow{p} p(V)$ is a homeomorphism. Since $W' = W \cap V$ is an open neighborhood of $\tilde x$ contained in $V$, it is mapped by $p$ homeomorhically onto $p(W')$. Thus $p(W')$ is open in $X$. Since $p(\tilde x) \in p(W')$, there exist an open path connected neighborhood $U$ of  $p(\tilde x)$ such that $U \subset p(W')$. Hence $W'' = p_V^{-1}(U)$ is an open path connected subset of $W'$ Since $W'$ is open in $\tilde X$, also $W''$ is open in $\tilde X$. But clearly $\tilde x = p_V^{-1}(p(\tilde x)$, hence $\tilde x \in W'' \subset W$.
This shows that $\tilde X$ is locally path connected.

Let $\tilde X$ be locally path connected and $p$ be surjective.

Let $x \in X$ and $W$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. There exist $\tilde x \in \tilde X$ such that $p(\tilde x) =  x$ and an open neighborhood $V$ of $\tilde x$ such that $p(V)$ is open in $X$ and $p_V :  V \xrightarrow{p} p(V)$ is a homeomorphism. Then $W' = W \cap p(V)$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ and $p_V^{-1}(W')$ is open in $V$, thus also open in $\tilde X$. Clearly $\tilde x \in p_V^{-1}(W') \subset V$. Hence there exists an open path connected neighborhood $U$ of $\tilde x$ such that $U \subset p_V^{-1}(W')$. Since $U$ is open in $V$, also $p_V(U) = p(U)$ is open in $p(V)$, hence also open in $X$. By construction $p_V(U)$ is path connected and satisfies $x \in p_V(U) \subset p_V(p_V^{-1}(W')) = W' \subset W$.
This shows that $X$ is locally path connected.

This is very clear and helpful! Thank you very much!!
